# Nikah in Muslim community

Tags: nikah

In muslim community, if a woman has had sex with a man, and she is pregnant, and in the state of her pregnancy, can she marry the man with whom she has had sex? Does Islam accept that nikah? I want the opinion of only a Sunni Muslim scholar.

Comment: You should add at least the tag zina, maybe pregnency or something similar too.

Answer (score 1):

Assalam o Allaikum.

Obviously, she can marry him. But the intercourse that they both had is still considered as Zinna (Haram) and you both need to ask for forgiveness. May Allah forgive you both. Ameen.

For your further reference https://hadithoftheday.com/adultery/

Comment: there is no mention of pregnancy. I ask that in pregnancy she can marry the same man! Is it halal in Islam?

Comment: When it is mentioned intercourse, then obviously whether she is pregnant or not, it does not matter, brother.

Comment: In fact you didn't answer the question, because people who commit zina need to  repentent sincerly before getting married and in case of pregnency the child would have the state of a child of zina... it is a much more difficult and detailled  topic than you try to make of it in your two sentences.

Comment: My brother, the question is simply, "can she marry the man with whom she has had sex?" and indeed this is not a complex question. 
By the way, what do you propose ??